# String trigger IRC script

Tags: irc

I need a script for IRC client (using KVirc) that will play a sound located somewhere on my hard drive whenever a certain piece of string is mentioned on the main channel. I assume such a thing is possible, but after some time of learning about scripting, I haven't found a way to do this on my own, and would be very grateful to anyone who would either write the piece of code or guide me how to do it myself.

Just a side note, this certain string I have in mind is not an exact string where all the characters are defined, but just first few letters, I assume the $ character is a substitute for all the text after the defined string.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, I hope I'm not too late xD

Open up KVIrc, hold ALT and press ENTER, it will bring up small console.
In there just copy this:

```
    /event(OnChannelMessage,sounds) { %match_string = "abccc";
%music_file = "C:\\YouTubeMp3\\Selo\ Gori\\Céline\ Dion\ -\ My\ Heart\ Will\ Go\ On-WNIPqafd4As.flv";
if($str.match(%match_string*,$3)) snd.play %music_file;
}
```

Of course, you should change %match_string and %music_file path, if you have spaces in path just escape them with backslash (), just like I did it.

If you have any questions or you need something else for KVIrc feel free to contact me on Rizon IRC network, nickname is DonVitoCorleone.